# Test the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^nx^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} $

Tags: uniform-convergence

Test the uniform convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^nx^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} $$

I have tried the tests listed in my book as well as the definitional method. Nothing seems to work. Need help/hint.

My work:

Using partial sum method

$S_n=\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{2^nx^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2n}}= 1+\frac{2}{1+x^2}+\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4}+\frac{8x^7}{1+x^6}+\frac{16x^{15}}{1+x^8}+...+\frac{2^nx^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} $

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: You should type your attempt.

Comment: There is nothing substantial to write. It's not like I got stuck at some step. Either the tests do not apply or I am not able to imagine what the first step would be like. Can you give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: I am aware of the partial sums method. The series would be convergent if the sum of its first $n$ terms is a definite finite number. But I can't say I got far with this method either. I will make an edit and include my work on this method.

Comment: Ok, I apparently wasn't clear at all. Let me try again then. First step should be asking is whether this converges at all. Have to proven it converges pointwise at all first? If so, where does it converge?

Comment: Sorry, Isn't denominator $1+x^{2^n}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses: No it isn't. There is no typing error

Comment: Before considering Weierstrass' test, you can narrow down your search by considering some necessary conditions. For sufficiently large $n$, we must have
$$2^nx^{2^{n}-1}< 1+x^{2n} $$
For which $x$ might this be the case?

Comment: It's difficult to give you advice since you contradict yourself. You say that pre conditions on partial sum test (I assume you are talking about taking the limit) are not met and yet you are attempting to apply this method.
You didn't mention d'Alembert's or Cauchy's test.